# Cross section of fiber bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $P \rightarrow M$ be a fiber bundle with typical fiber $F$. What is the definition of a  cross section of the fiber bundle $P$,  is it another name of a section or is it a different terminology ?

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you .